# Procces of recursion in Tibco

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

I need to list all the files in specific directory(for e.g D:\TestFolder*) and let's say that TestFolder has three subfolders and those three subfolders have another three subfolders and files(png,jpg,txt),and another descendants...and then send them all in email with Send mail ativity.

I tryed with ListFiles activity but i only get the first subfolders/files...how can i retrieve all descendants from the specific file?

I know that this is related with procces of recursion but i don't know how to solve this in tibco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListFiles returns the type for each element found (if selected directories or files+directories). If you designed your main process to work on a single directory you can add a iterate loop calling it with all elements[type = "directory"] as iteration statement. This will result in a recursive iteration (depth-first is done synchronously, breadth-first if spawned).

Answer (score 0):

Tibco Designer is not allowing you to select the sub process with same name as main process in tibco designer but you always can type the process name manually in "call process" activity for simple recursion implementation.

[image]

here is the code for printing all the files and folders names recursively
https://github.com/dowid/tibco/tree/master/RecursionTest